# Summarize ids of student project

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As you cann see, projectgroup is not the same as projectid, but the projectgroup should have the same projectid.

```
d = {'Studentid': [1, 2, 3 , 1, 1, 3, 1 ,1]
     ,'Studentname': ['Bob', 'Jason', 'Jackson', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob' 'Bob']
     , 'projectgroup': ['The fantastic', 'New', 'Banana' , 'The fantastic', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana']
     ,'projectid': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()
```

[image]

---

How could I print the output which project group has how many IDs, only the projects with different ids?
For example The `fantastic has 2 different ids (1 and 4)`, `Banana has 2 different  ids (3,5)`

And how could I summarize these numbers, like

[image]

---

My dataframe

[image]

With the help of @venky__
I got this (The picture shows what I have)

[image]

the following picture shows what I want. You can see only the unique values should merged.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate at project level and the merge it with base file

```
from tabulate import tabulate
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd
d = {
    'Studentid': [1, 2, 3 , 1, 1, 1, 1]
    ,'Studentname': ['Bob', 'Jason', 'Jackson', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob']
    , 'projectgroup': ['The fantastic', 'New', 'Banana' , 'The fantastic', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana']
    ,'projectid': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df)
project_df = df.groupby('projectgroup').agg(project_list = ('projectid',set),
                                            unique_projects=('projectid','nunique'))

pd.merge(df[['Studentid','Studentname','projectgroup']].drop_duplicates(),project_df,how='left',on='projectgroup')
```

**Output:**

```
Studentid Studentname   projectgroup project_list  unique_projects
1         Bob  The fantastic       {1, 4}                2
2       Jason            New          {2}                1
3     Jackson         Banana       {3, 5}                2
1         Bob         Banana       {3, 5}                2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and how could I print the output which project group has how many IDs, only the projects with different ids?

Comment: I added a column called unique_projects  which will satisfy what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you very much! @venky__ is there an option to count only the unique projectids? In this example it merged all ids togehter, also when the id is added. For example | [1, 4,1..]

Comment: Yes can be done updated the answer. convert the `list` to `set`

Comment: thank you very much! Last option :/, in the output at projectid it prints all ids..., could I also merged only the unqiue projectids togehter? The count is perfect.

Comment: Can you help with what should be the output? I am unable to understand.the requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223908/discussion-between-igotyoulikethegoat-and-venky).

Comment: Hey can you check my code again cause i added the edit to include only unique values

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `projectgroup` and then apply `list` onto the `projectid` column of each group. Then convert the result to a dataframe and finally merge this with the original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Studentid': [1, 2, 3 , 1, 1]
     ,'Studentname': ['Bob', 'Jason', 'Jackson', 'Bob', 'Bob']
     , 'projectgroup': ['The fantastic', 'New', 'Banana' , 'The fantastic', 'Banana']
     ,'projectid': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

tmp_df = df.groupby('projectgroup').apply(lambda col: list(col['projectid'])).to_frame(name='list')

df = df.merge(t, left_on='projectgroup', right_index=True)
```

Here, `tmp_df` holds the `project_group` with the corresponding list.
I.e.

```
                list
projectgroup    
Banana          [3, 5]
New             [2]
The fantastic   [1, 4]
```

Comment: thank you very much! I want to count only the unique projectids. If the projectid is merged it shouldn't merged it agian. How could I do this ? :)